# Добавить значения в список List, который находится в словаре Dictionary

Tags: c#

Создал словарь с ключом типа String и значением Список.

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

Как добавить значения для ключа?

```
dict.Add(el.operation, ???);
```

Comment: Именно `List`? Без дженерика? типа `List<string>`

Comment: List<string> опечатка

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно создать список с данными и его вставить как значение. Например:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict= new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("text1"); 
list.Add("text2"); 
list.Add("text3"); 
list.Add("text4");

dict.Add(el.operation, list);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(Dict["идентификатор"] as List<тип>).Add("добавляемые данные");
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]